# como obtengo el valor correcto a un HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost);

Tags: java, android, http, post, http-post

tengo un metodo post. 
Que consume una Webservice que devuelve un  boolean (ws) (todo correcto hasta acá), como ya saben me devuelve un true o un false (que lo hace correcto)

¿Como puedo recuperar dicho resultado?.

este es e codigo

```
HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost); 
            final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
            if (entity == null) {
                Log.w("GIM", "The response has no entity.");
            } else {
                // que pongo acá para obtener el valor true o false
            }
```

el valor entity me devuelve

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><boolean xmlns="http://pda.gim/">true</boolean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que comúnmente se realiza es crear un `BufferedReader` para almacenar el valor de la respuesta,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><boolean xmlns="http://pda.gim/">true</boolean>
```

a partir de esta respuesta que es un xml, se realiza un parseo para obtener el valor del tag "boolean", al determinar su valor se puede usar la lógica que deseas en tu programa:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
try {
    BufferedReader reader = 
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
    String line = null;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }


    //En base a respuesta realiza parsing para obtener el valor del tag boolean.
    if (parseXml(sb.toString(), "boolean").equals("true")){
       //Contiene valor true.        
    }else{
       //No contiene valor true, por lo tanto es false.        
    } 

}catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace(); 
}catch (Exception e) { 
e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

este es un método usado en el anterior código, en el cual se envía la respuesta y el nombre del tag (en este caso "boolean") y obtenemos su valor:

```
  public String parseXml(String xml, String tag){
        try {
            boolean obtieneValor = false;
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
            xpp.setInput( new StringReader(xml)); 
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"Start document");
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"Start tag "+xpp.getName());
                    if(xpp.getName().equals(tag)) {
                        obtieneValor = true;
                    }
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"End tag "+xpp.getName());
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    //Log.d(TAG,"valor Text "+xpp.getText());
                    if(obtieneValor && xpp.getText()!= null){
                       return xpp.getText();
                    }
                    obtieneValor = false;
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "";
    }
```

Este método puede ser útil para determinar el valor de cualquier tag en tu respuesta xml.

```
String valor =  parseXml(<respuesta XML>, <nombre de tag>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder acceder al valor de la respuesta, puedes crear un `Document` con el cual tu respuesta XML se convierte en un objeto que puedes manipular y acceder a sus propiedades, te dejo un método que te puede ayudar a convertir un `String` a un `Document`

```
public static Document documentoDesdeString(String xml) throws Exception {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = 
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    return builder.parse(is);
}
```

Ya que tienes tu objeto `Document`, puedes acceder a la propiedad `boolean`que estas buscando con el siguiente código:

```
try {
    Document doc = documentoDeString(xml);
    Node xmlBoolean = doc.getElementsByTagName("boolean").item(0);
    String booleanValue = xmlBoolean.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

`booleanValue` ahora tendrá el valor de *true* según tu ejemplo.

Comment: el campo "xml" de donde lo obtengo.. tengo el valor ??? disculpa.

Comment: En tu ejemplo sería tu objectio `entity`, lo puedes convertir en `String` de la siguiente forma: `EntityUtils.toString(entity);`

Answer (score 0):

El API de [Apache HttpCore](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) provee una clase de Utilería para obtener el valor String de un objeto `HttpEntity`:

```
String valorString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
```

Una vez obtenido el valor String, solo habría que realizar el Cast al valor requerido (en este caso a booleano)

```
if(valorString != null){
    Boolean valor = (Boolean)valorString;
}
```

Comment: al ingresar String valorString = EntityUtils.toString(entity); me aparece este error. String valorString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

Comment: En android, actualmente las library apache son marcadas como obsoletas  https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client se puede habilitar su uso pero la tendencia es dejar de usarlas.

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr lo que quieres primero tienes que obtener el contenido de la respuesta, eso lo logras con `EntityUtils.toString()` al que le pasas como parametro el contenido de la respuesta y este lo convierte a `String`.

Para leer el xml obtenido puedes utilizar varias librerías, como la librería **JDOM**. Para utilizar la librería **JDOM** debes integrarla en tu proyecto. Puedes descargas el **jar** de la librería desde [aquí](http://www.jdom.org/dist/binary/jdom-2.0.6.zip) e integrarla manualmente, en este [tutorial](https://es.wikihow.com/a%C3%B1adir-un-jar-a-un-proyecto-en-eclipse-(java)) se explica como integrar librerias manualmente en Eclipce. O puedes integrarla utilizando las dependencias que proporciona la librería, [aqui](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom/2.0.2) puedes encontrar dependencias para integrarla con Gradle, Maven u otras herramientas de construcción.

Con la libreria integradas ya tienes todo lo necesario para leer el xml.

```
    HttpResponse response = mHttpClient.execute(httppost); 
    final HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
    if (entity == null) {
        Log.w("GIM", "The response has no entity.");
    } else {

        SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
        Document doc = null;

        try {

            // Obtienes el xml de la respuesta
            String xml = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            // Pasas el xml a saxBuilder para poder leerlo y extraer la informacion
            doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(xml));
        } catch (JDOMException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Obtienes el valor almacenado en el xml
        String valor = doc.getRootElement().getText();

        // Imprimes el valor
        System.out.println(message);
```